# inline conditionals for assignment

Tags: shell-script, zsh

Is there an "inline-equivalent" to expressions like the following?:

```
if [[ $VERBOSE == 1 ]]; then
  V=$FOO
else
  V=
fi
```

I'm thinking of something like this in `perl`, for example:

```
$V = $VERBOSE ? $FOO : undef;
```

(BTW, my interest is not so much in the business of reducing five lines to one, since one could always re-write the shell snippet as

```
if [[ $VERBOSE == 1 ]]; then V=$FOO; else V=; fi
```

but rather in a single conditional expression that is equivalent to a multi-statement `if`-construct.)

In case there's a difference, I'm interested primarily in the answer for `zsh`, but also in the one for `bash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zsh being zsh, there is a cryptic way:

```
V=${${VERBOSE#0}:+$FOO}
```

This sets `V` to the value of `FOO` if `VERBOSE` is a nonzero number, and to the empty string if `VERBOSE` is empty or `0`.

```
V=${${${VERBOSE/#/a}:#a1}:+foo}
```

This sets `V` to the value of `FOO` if `VERBOSE` is the exact string `1`, and to the empty string otherwise.

Now forget this and use the clear syntax with `if` or `case`.

If `FOO` is numeric, you can use the `?:` operator in an arithmetic expression. The else case has to be numeric as well.

```
((V = VERBOSE ? FOO : 0))
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, the closest I can think of would be

```
[[ $VERBOSE == 1 ]] && V="YES" || V="NO"
```

For example:

```
$ VERBOSE=0
$ [[ $VERBOSE == 1 ]] && V="YES" || V="NO"; echo $V
NO
$ VERBOSE=1
$ [[ $VERBOSE == 1 ]] && V="YES" || V="NO"; echo $V
YES
```

The above works for bash and zsh (and most other shells).

Comment: (_most other shells_ being `ksh`. That's `ksh` syntax here).

Answer (score 4):

You can use case/switches in Bash for this too. Just remember that they can't evaluate logic:

```
case "$VERBOSE" in
  1) V="YES" ;;
  *) V="NO"  ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 4):

Competing for the most cryptic:

```
$ echo ${${(z):-NO YES}[2-!VERBOSE]}
NO
$ VERBOSE=123
$ echo ${${(z):-NO YES}[2-!VERBOSE]}
YES
```

Or:

```
$ echo ${${(z):-NO YES}:!!VERBOSE:1}
YES
```

Comment: I'll be chewing on these for some time...  Thanks!